# Учетная книжка с описью выданных на временное пользование изданий

Tags: названия

В библиотеке в неё заносят сведения о читателе, перечень книг на домашнем абонементе и т. д.

Как называеися эта книжка (документ, карточка)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотекари называют такой документ «читательским формуляром».
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]